# Displaying Data with Spring JPA and REST

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, spring-rest

Following these tutorials [1](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/), [2](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-rest/), I successfully made a RESTful Spring application combined with JPA. Currently, I have 3 drivers in my Driver repository.

My problem is when I go on localhost:8080/driver, it says this:

```
{
  "_embedded" : {
"driver" : [ {
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/driver/1"
    },
    "driver" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/driver/1"
    }
  }
}, {
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/driver/2"
    },
    "driver" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/driver/2"
    }
  }
}, {
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/driver/3"
    },
    "driver" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/driver/3"
    }
  }
} ]
  },
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
  "href" : "http://localhost:8080/driver"
   },
    "profile" : {
  "href" : "http://localhost:8080/profile/driver"
   },
   "search" : {
    "href" : "http://localhost:8080/driver/search"
}
  },
 "page" : {
"size" : 20,
"totalElements" : 3,
"totalPages" : 1,
"number" : 0
  }
}
```

and when I go onto a particular's drivers page, something like localhost:8080/driver/1, it says this:

```
{
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/driver/1"
    },
    "driver" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/driver/1"
    }
  }
}
```

In my Driver Entity Class, I have fields like firstName, lastName, telephone and stuff like that. My question is: is there a way I can display on it either localhost:8080/driver or localhost:8080/driver/1? So that it looks similar to this:

```
 {
  "firstName" : "Frodo",
  "lastName" : "Baggins",
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/people/1"
    }
   }
}
```

I know the fields are properly saved in the database, because I can successfully search for them, but I haven't yet found an example of how to display them, except POSTing with curl.

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help!

Edit: This is my Starter class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
 public class StartServer implements    ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {


private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(StartServer.class);


public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(StartServer.class, args);

}

@Override
public void onApplicationEvent(final ContextRefreshedEvent event) {

}

@Bean
public CommandLineRunner demo(DriverRepository repository) {
    return (args) -> {
        repository.save(new Driver("Jack", "Bauer"));
        repository.save(new Driver("JackY", "Aasd"));
        repository.save(new Driver("JackMe", "Commou"));

        // fetch all customers
        log.info("Drivers found with findAll():");
        log.info("-------------------------------");
        for (Driver driver : repository.findAll()) {
            log.info(driver.toString());
        }
        log.info("");

        Driver driver = repository.findOne(1L);
        log.info("Customer found with findOne(1L):");
        log.info("--------------------------------");
        log.info(driver.toString());
        log.info("");

        // fetch customers by last name
        log.info("Driver found with findByLastName('Bauer'):");
        log.info("--------------------------------------------");
        for (Driver bauer : repository.findByLastName("Bauer")) {
            log.info(bauer.toString());
        }
        log.info("");
    };
}



}
```

And my DriverRepository class:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "driver", path = "driver")

public interface DriverRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Driver, Long> {

List<Driver> findByLastName(@Param("name") String name);
}
```

I do not have a Controller Class for /driver, because the  @RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "driver", path = "driver") took care of it for me.

My Driver Entity class:

```
@Entity
public class Driver {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;
String firstName;
String lastName;

protected Driver() {

}

public Driver(String firstName, String lastName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return String.format( "Customer[id=%d, firstName='%s', lastName='%s']",
            id, firstName, lastName);
}


}
```

Comment: You don't have properties, you only have fields. Add a getter/setter for the fields you want to expose.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thank you! I totally forgot about these.